# Assign variable in array key

Tags: php, arrays, prestashop

I'm working on prestashop module, that will send additional data to Google Analytics with cURL. 
And I'm stuck with how to assign iteration count variable into array key.

For example:

```
'prXnm' => $order_detail['product_name'],
    'prXid' => $order_detail['product_id'],
    'prXpr' => $order_detail['product_price'],
```

Where X is a number and should do something like 
`count($order_detail['product_name']);`

How can I implement X into an array? Because `'prcount($order_detail['product_name'])nm' => $order_detail['product_name'],` is not working

Comment: Including a count into a key name doesn't make any sense. If you have two products which have the same count, you will get identical keys which is not valid in PHP.

Comment: Ok, I see your point and I'm just starting learning php:) What should i do to count iterations? Create foreach loop and count iterations inside loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try concatenation like:

```php
$x = count($order_detail['product_name']);
$result = array(
  "pr${x}nm" => $order_detail['product_name'],
  "pr${x}id" => $order_detail['product_id'],
  "pr${x}pr" => $order_detail['product_price'],
);
```

> **Notes:**
>
> 1. As already [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/nick) pointed out, including count into a key name doesn't make much sense, but I guess you just wanted to provide a sample ;-)
> 2. The double-quote in PHP is specially helpful for concatenating, but the single-quote should be used to improve performance (PHP does not search or handle dollar-signs in single quotes).

Answer (score 1):

```
$number = 3;
$array1 = array("test$number" => "Sample");
$array2 = array("test".$number => "Sample");

print_r($array1); //Array ( [test3] => Sample )
print_r($array2); //Array ( [test3] => Sample )
```

You should learn the PHP basis.

Answer (score 0):

you can use double quote for the array key, then inject the variable using [curly braces syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

```
<?php

$i = count($order_detail['product_name']);

$arr = [
    "pr${i}nm" => $order_detail['product_name'],
    "pr${i}id" => $order_detail['product_id'],
    "pr${i}pr" => $order_detail['product_price'],
];
```